# How to send multiple files and folders to local server express

Tags: node.js, express, server, localhost

My project has files, in the screenshot below. My task is to run the whole project on a local express server. But only index.html is displayed without styles. The static file method doesn't work either. How can I fix this?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ8JD.png)

server.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'css'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'img'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'js'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'sass'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'vendor'))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on 3000');
});
```

Comment: add:

`const path = require('path');` ad the begining and then instead `__dirname + 'css'` use path.join(__dirname, 'css');`

Comment: @Seti Still doesn't work

Comment: are that directories existing?

Comment: @Seti Yes, as on the screen

Comment: try:   app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css')));

Comment: and check if you can fetch css files